# Getting field value from ACF via AJAX when using a custom query returns null?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I can't get the ACF custom fields while doing a query. It's always returning null or just return nothing:

```
/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/PagStream/inc/helpers/ajax-functions.php:112:
array (size=2)
  'group_header' => null
  'flexible_post_components' => null
```

This is my code:

JS:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("#load-more").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      var button = $(this),
  
        data = {
          action: "loadmore",
          query: loadmore_params.posts, 
          page: loadmore_params.current_page,
        };
  
      var textButton = button.text();
  
      $.ajax({
        url: loadmore_params.ajaxurl, 
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (v) {
          button.text("Loading..."); 
        },
        success: function (data) {
          if (data) {
            button.text(textButton);
            $(".grid__inner").append(data);

            loadmore_params.current_page++;
            
            if (loadmore_params.current_page == loadmore_params.max_page)
              button.remove(); 

          } else {
            button.remove(); 
          }
        },
        error: function(){
          console.log('error')
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Localize php:

```
    global $wp_query;

    wp_localize_script('domain_js', 'loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
        'posts' => json_encode($wp_query->query_vars), 
        'current_page' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ));
```

and the handler:

```
function loadmore_ajax_handler(){

    $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    query_posts( $args );

    if (have_posts()) :
        // run the loop
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();

            $hero = get_field('group_header', get_the_id());

            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($hero);
            echo '</pre>';

            if ($hero) : 
            
                echo '<pre>';
                var_dump($hero['reading_time']);
                echo '</pre>';

            ?>
<?php
            endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    die;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'loadmore_ajax_handler'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'loadmore_ajax_handler');
```

'group_header' is a group field;
'reading_time' is a sub-field of 'group_header'.

I have already searched on ACF pro forum, here and nothing has helped so far.

Tried to reset all queries and change the query.

Outside the AJAX-load-more code the query works properly, but when I'm try to use it in my AJAX call it's not working.

Does anybody has a clue? Please!

Comment: From ACF's documentation, it sounds like you're supposed to use [get_sub_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/) when looping through a Repeater field or a Flexible Content field. It doesn't seem like you're doing that here which would explain why you get `null` values. Is this `reading_time` field inside a Repeater or a Flexible Content field?

Comment: Hi cabrera. I'm using the group field, and 'reading_time' is a sub-field.

heres another example of the handler: 

 if (have_posts()) :
  // run the loop
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();

   $hero = get_field('group_header', get_the_id());

   echo '<pre>';
   var_dump($hero);
   echo '</pre>';

   if ($hero) : 
   
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($hero['reading_time']);
    echo '</pre>';

   ?>
<?php

   endif;

  endwhile;
 endif;

this return null...

i'm also trying to use query_posts()

Comment: What do you get if you get all the fields from a given post using [get_fields(post_id)](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/)? Is `group_header` one of the fields it returns with any data?

Comment: @wouch i can see all fields, but they are null